# what is vdb partition in this manual

Tags: partitioning

i'm trying to do this manual as it say [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ClusterStack/Natty#A.5Bboth.5D_Install_Pacemaker_and_Corosync) but in the DRBD Section it says VDB partition that don't understand what kind of partition is that ???
could any one help !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vdb stands for vd second device b

```
vd : Virtio Block Device
b: second device with the above type
```

It is usually used in virtual machines like kvm and virt-manager from [Virtio Disks](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Virtio)

They will at at this form:

```
 /dev/vd[a-z][1-9]
```

from redhat:

> **Device naming**
>
> virtio-blk devices are represented by the guests with
> files whose names start with /dev/vd. This  is unlike devices in a
> bare-metal system, whose names typically start with /dev/sd

Answer (score 0):

The vdb is defined in the manual as follows:

> Prepare Partitions
>
> The first step in setting up DRBD is to prepare the partitions/disks
>   to be used as DRBD devices. **We are assuming that we have a disk (vdb)**
>   on which we will create a partition table, and a primary partition of
>   1Gb for the DRBD device.

I suggest you re-read the manual from the top. I guess you will get what they are talking about, if you just take the time to understand it all

Comment: i know that and i read the manual carefully but don't know what the exactly vdb is i mean is that kind of partition should i create ? cause i have 3 partition as sda in my virtual linux like this : first partiton is for linux second as extended and still empty and the last one is for swap . so what is your suggestion for me ?